# Is Volkswagen a synonym for a small car?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I have been watching a documentation in which a professor said "Rocks in the size of a **Volkswagen**" and meanwhile the german translation was "Steine in der Größe eines **Kleinwagens**", which means "Rock in the size of a **small car**".
I could not really find something online, so maybe this is an urban saying? Or just an habit of this prof? Or is it something completely normal to say?

Comment: Perhaps he was thinking of the VW 'Beetle', a car whose appearance is easily visualised by many people.

Comment: The "in" confuses me. Unless it's meant in the same sense as: "Dresses in size 10" or "shirts in the size of a zeppelin" or whatever. But it sounds decidedly unnatural in this context.

Comment: How old was this piece? Once upon a time the Beetle was the only car that VW made, so the comparison was pretty uncomplicated.  As noted "in" is unusual.

Comment: Writers may use familar objects or ideas to indicate quantities. In the UK we often hear that something is the size or height of one or more London buses, or that an area of land is some multiple of the area of Wales. These have become clichés. Regarding the Volkswagen thing, I think 'small car' would work just as well.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a cultural difference. The metaphor is fairly understandable in the US, where VW is mostly known for the Beetle and anything smaller than a pickup truck is a "small car", but could be confusing to Europeans where VW has more presence and VW cars aren't really considered particularly small.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski - here in Europe we have both TV and movies, and we know (how could we not?) what kind of cars many Americans drive (which are 'large' to us) so I still say 'small car' would work here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yeah, and that's what the German translator went with - but the connotation of "Volkswagen" with "a small car" would probably be lost on the European audience if the phrase was translated literally.

Comment: When I was a boy, a Volkswagen was a Beetle; now they make cars from small (the **up!** [sic]) to what I would call 'medium/large' (e.g. Passat), I wonder how old the 'documentation' and the professor are.

Comment: "rocks in the size of x" is not idiomatic in English. That's why source language speakers should not be translating into target languages. That said, there is no reason one cannot use any brand or product one likes: **rocks the size of a Volkswagen Beetle**.

Comment: @Lambie but that presumably incorrect phrase was in the *source* text - at least that's how I'm reading the question. (Also, you don't have to be a native speaker to speak idiomatic English)

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I don't care, it is not idiomatic in English. The professor may not be an English speaker at all. Who knows? I believe I made a general statement that source language speakers should not be translating into target languages unless 100% bilingual which is rare.

Comment: @Lambie then that statement is not supported by the example in question. (And personally I disagree with it, but that's a whole other discussion).

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I believe your comments are correct and you should post them as an answer.

Comment: I agree that it seems unidiomatic to say "in the size of" here (rather than "the size of"), but that seems irrelevant to the main point.  Also, the fact that the question mentions a translation may be predisposing some to suggest that the professor is a non-native speaker.  There are other possibilities - perhaps the professor was misquoted, or perhaps it was a slip of the tongue.  Occasionally, native speakers speaking off-the-cuff come up with infelicitous or even unidiomatic wording.  But that's a separate point from the actual question.

Comment: I have a friend who used to be a 'young fogey' and has seamlessly morphed into an old one. He used to insist on saying 'Folksvagen', or else call them 'KdF-wagens'.

Comment: It could also be, that the professor did not say the "in". I was researching while the documentation was still playing, so the quote was what I remembered, not exactly what he said. [Here is the link to the documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8NEE7NRk00)

Answer (score 5):

While it's not an "urban saying"* or any specific English idiom, there's a bit of a cultural distinction here.

It's safe to assume that the original lecture was delivered to a primarily American audience. In the US, Volkswagen is a brand associated with small, compact cars - most notably the various variants of the [Beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Beetle). So the metaphor works - a rock "the size of a Volkswagen" is roughly the size of a car, but closer to a Beetle than to a [Chevy Impala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevrolet_Impala) or other full-sized cars the Americans are more accustomed to.

On the other hand, if translated directly to German and intended for a German audience, the metaphor loses its meaning - there's nothing special about a size of a Volkswagen in Europe, both because Europeans are more familiar with other Volkswagen models such as a [Passat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Passat) or [Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Golf), and because full-sized cars are notably less popular on European streets. So "the size of a Volkswagen" means little to someone in Europe, for whom Volkswagen is just an average car.

Hence the indirect translation to *Kleinwagen* - a "small car" (or rather, a [specific class of small cars](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinwagen)).

---

* Side note: [you might want to avoid that phrasing](https://www.theguardian.com/music/shortcuts/2018/aug/14/urban-time-stop-hackneyed-term-black-music).